# Return correct data type from XML element with xsi:type attribute specified

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Does the .NET framework have a built-in API for parsing some of the primitive data types of XML Schema and turning them into appropriate .NET data types? For example:

```
<someElement 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2013-03-01T18:36:00Z</someElement>
```

I'd like to write some C# code that would key off of the `xsi:type` attribute and give me the equivalent .NET data type, ideally with some built-in API from .NET. I have just recently found the `XmlConvert` class with it's several `ToXXX()` static methods (like `ToDateTime()`, but I'd want it to pick the appropriate type automatically.

**Important caveat:** I'd strongly prefer if possible to avoid using the `xsd.exe` tool that auto generates C# class declarations based on an XML schema file.

Comment: XElement has explicit conversions you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx. That might help you, but that doesn't really solve the problem of doing it automatically by looking at the xsi:type attribute. Maybe someone can chime in one that.

Comment: There is nothing that will do this automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing that does what you want automatically in .NET.

The closest thing is the code generated automatically by the objecte serializer/deserializers - that can actually read and use `xsi:type` to generate objects of different classes when de-serializing a XML element, but it does not really work for primitive types liked dates (and is quite cumbersome to use - you have to declare classes and de-serialize them).